# Languages Supported by NLP Tools / Translation

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp, gate

Is there some documentation on the number of Languages supported by these NLP Tool Kits - 
Python NLTK
Open-NLP
GATE
Stanford CoreNLP

We are specifically looking for Simplified and Traditional Chinese, Malay, Tamil, Bahasa Indonesia, Korean, Vietnamese, Cantonese.

From what I understand a very few of these would be supported. So, if we use Google translate to convert from Local to English and then Apply NLP rules - How Good/Bad/Recommended the Approach will be? Is there any community expertise on NLP on Translated Data

thanks,
Manish

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/alvations/NTU-MC (Disclaimer: Shameless plug)

Comment: Unfortunately, your question cannot be answered like this. Whether a language is supported depends on the task you want to accomplish. Three examples to make this clear: 1) NLTK provides grammars. Any language that can be described with a grammar is supported 2) GATE provides JAPE (regEx based annotations) anything that can be described is supported 3) Stanford Core NLP is mainly used as POS Tagger or statistical parser. This is done by training a model. Any language, for which a model is present for this task is supported. Please specify what exactly you mean by "apply NLP rules".

Comment: For a bunch of languages which are all unrelated to English, choosing English as the interlingua has to be an exceptionally poor choice.

Comment: @thorsten - You are right that we could build the grammar / train the model. However the concern is that that is an inherently manual task since someone has to define grammars and provide tagged data for models to learn. The reason to use built in grammars/models is to save that time. This is especially true for new languages where the the language expertise is missing. Thus the  approach  of translation and then English Grammar. Our hope is that except for Chinese that is essentially grammar less.. It should atleast work for the remaining  languages.

Comment: @tripleee - Can you throw some light as to why would translation not work out. Any practical experiences with it? Since Google Translate works well with (atleast Indian Languages) for grammar  translation too, we think it will be worth the time for South  Asian Languages too.

Comment: Because even round-tripping to English and then back to the original language tends to introduce errors. For (culturally if not strictly linguistically) related languages, round-tripping is somewhat less likely to introduce errors because the languages share more concepts and constructions. But of course, the overall feasibility heavily depends on how general you need the solution to be. If it's all just, say, weather reports, you can probably get perfect accuracy with nearly any method.

Answer (score 0):

GATE has some plugins for Non-English languages. Additional information you could find at https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:misc-creole:language-plugins
But it would be great if you will clarify your question a bit in terms of requirements.